# Reason to take more loading time of asp.net page and how to reduce it

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webserver, asp.net-webpages

I have the following queries regarding the loading time of asp.net page. 
Anyone can help.
What are the possibilities of asp.net page consuming more loading time?.
How to reduce the loading time of asp.net web page?

Comment: What are you doing in the page?

Comment: Consuming data from database and display it on a Gridview. Then Edit and delete operations on those data in the Gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Images used

   - The images used should be optimized and consider low file size.
   - Allow Caching of images
2. Reduce number of scripts and stylesheets

   - Try minimizing and combining CSS  and script files
3. Enable HTTP Compression
4. Compilation should be on release mode ie, remove `<compilation debug="true"/>` from web.config
5. Check the Viewstate, big viewstates slow downs the page.
6. If you are consuming the database, try database level paging, if the number of records are higher. Consider fetching only the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

**Five possibilities I can think of (aside from some advanced caching techniques and such):**

Improper sizing of the web server for ASP.NET (i.e. thought a server sized for classic ASP would be fine)

Forgetting to remove  from the web.config and getting less than optimal code.

JIT for the first visit

Code embedded in the page (as opposed to the compiled code-behind) that requires compilation before and in addition to the JIT.

ViewState (for ASP.NET WebForms) gets too big.
Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting data from a database on startup, I would pay attention not to:

Select not needed data from the database doing stuff like

```
SELECT * from TabelX
```

I would specify exactly what columns to use

Don't load all the data in a list at the beginning, but load id only when you need it. More than this, I would load like only 20-50-100 rows, only those that can be shown on the page at a time.

If you are joining large number of rows, I would consider creating views.